# Ubuntu 18.10 - External Displays connected to Thunderbolt3 docking station don't work on re-plugging tb3

Tags: kernel, 18.10

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on a Lenovo T480.

Hot-replugging of the Thunderbolt 3 Dock with two attached Displays over HDMI freezes the Device until I unplug the Docking station again.
Booting with the attached device works normally.

The Issue seems to be related to this Bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813663

which was fixed with the release of 4.15.0-45.

It seems that the fix is not part of the latest 4.18 kernel. Anybody having the same Issues with 18.10?

Comment: This one also seems to be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1752165

Comment: I worked around the problem by using Kernel 5.0